# How can I add basic authentication to cy.origin?

Tags: cypress

The website used for user authentication is protected using Basic Authentication. How can I switch to a different baseUrl while still using Basic Authentication to view the page?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the Cypress docs [Add basic auth headers](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit#Add-basic-auth-headers)

> Cypress will automatically apply the right authorization headers if you're attempting to visit an application that requires **Basic Authentication**.
>
> Provide the username and password in the auth object. Then all subsequent requests matching the origin you're testing will have these attached at the network level.
>
> ```js
> cy.visit('https://www.acme.com/', {
>  auth: {
>    username: 'wile',
>    password: 'coyote',
>  },
> })
> ```

so it's nothing to do with the `cy.origin()` per-se, rather the `cy.visit()` that takes you to that other origin.